# Is my SSD or my SATA Controller failing?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I am having sporadic disk read errors. Ordinarily, I would assume the SSD is dying, but there's a history to these problems:

- **Spring 2017**: I purchased a new Samsung SSD 850 Pro *(so it was barely 2 years old when the problems began)*
- **Summer 2018**: A lightning strike occurred, entering my home through the landline, destroying my router, the USB/Ethernet adapter, the Raspberry PI behind it, went through my switch (unharmed), through my motherboard (unharmed, probably), destroyed my USB printer and the USB hub in my screen
- **Winter 2018 / Spring 2019**: When I turn on my PC in the morning, Linux boots fine, but booting Windows fails, printing "*hard disk read error, press any key to reboot*". Booting into Windows after 1-2 hours of Linux uptime generally works.

And that's how the issue has remained for the past 2 years. It's neither worsening nor improving.

---

I've checked with Samsung's "SSD Magician" software, but it claims that my SSD is in perfect condition with no bad / moved sectors.

That Windows only boots semi-reliably after 1-2 hours of uptime looks like a thermal effect to me.

Linux seems to experience the same issues on the early morning boot, but is more resilient. Here's what was in my `dmesg` this morning, for example:

```
[    3.678283] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x6800001 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
[    3.678285] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[    3.678287] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
[    3.678289] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[    3.678294] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:00:e0:5a:dd/00:00:33:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 16384 in
                        res 40/00:00:e0:5a:dd/00:00:33:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)                                                       
...
[    3.678335] ata1: hard resetting link
[    3.993153] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
...
[    4.000672] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    4.000677] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[    4.000681] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[    4.000686] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 33 dd 5a e0 00 00 20 00
[    4.000691] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 870144736 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
...
[    4.000796] ata1: EH complete
[    5.062260] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    5.282271] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x4000 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
[    5.282273] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[    5.282276] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
[    5.282279] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[    5.282286] ata1.00: cmd 60/68:70:20:65:89/00:00:27:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 53248 in
                        res 40/00:70:20:65:89/00:00:27:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)                                                       
[    5.282287] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[    5.282292] ata1: hard resetting link
...
[    5.604751] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[    5.604755] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#14 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[    5.604759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#14 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[    5.604765] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 27 89 65 20 00 00 68 00
[    5.604769] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 663315744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 13 prio class 0
[    5.604788] ata1: EH complete
[   28.274273] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x60c1 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
[   28.274276] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[   28.274278] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
[   28.274281] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   28.274286] ata1.00: cmd 60/50:00:b0:4f:19/00:00:30:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 40960 in
                        res 40/00:68:28:d6:b8/00:00:26:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
```

Full log here: [Full dmesg SATA error log on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/y0nTRZWq)

Is there any clue whether I need to replace my motherboard or my SSD to rid myself of these issues?

Comment: I'd at least change the SATA cable & port before spending money on any other fix. Check there are no sharp bends in it & that it is under no strain. Spray with contact cleaner too.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are getting indeed mean that some parts of SSD are bad. Though from this log alone you cannot say if it's motherboard or SSD (or both). What you can do is the process of elimination by cross-testing individual components (e.g. try motherboard with a different SSD, try SSD with a different motherboard etc.). For the first (and easiest) step, replace the cable and plug the SSD into a different port.

SSD might still appear to work when you boot an OS (subject to what data is actually being used, how the drive remaps the inaccessible sectors, temperature etc.) but since it is not working reliably it is the same as not working at all.

When testing SSD, don't rely on `fsck` alone - use `badblocks` in read/write/verify mode. This will guarantee that every sector is tested, including free space. To account for thermal effect, allow it to run 3 passes or more, and if you still get any errors like those, get a new one.

Comment: *but since it is not working reliably it is the same as not working at all* - that's the fun part, after booting it's completely reliable. Never hung, never crashed, never a read error. Linux kernel messages show that the interface enters an error state and resets maybe 4 times per day.

Comment: In any case, badblocks (in read-only mode) only found an error when the interface happened to be reset while testing. I ultimately replaced the SSD with a Samsung 860 and the errors are gone. Same cable, new SSD in same location.